# jQuery prevent other events after a click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prevent multiple clicks on links and items, which is causing problems.

I am using jQuery to bind click events to buttons (jQuery UI) and image links (`<a><img /></a>`).

Is there a way to do-once-for-all prevent other events from firing after a click occurs?

Or do I have to maintain a global variable called _isProcessing and set it to true for each event handler?

Thanks

Edit: (clarification)
Thanks for your answers, my problem isn't preventing the bubbling of the event, but preventing multiple concurrent clicks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"other events"*? Other event handlers on same element? Or on its ancestor elements? Or on the entire page? Could you please clarify your specific need?

Comment: So if I have an image link called "Add service", which adds a row to a table on my page. If I click more than once it adds two.  No other rows should be added in teh time after the click was done, and before the row has been created.

Comment: @Russell - Yes, I added an answer below to address that.

Comment: Thanks @patrick :) I hadn't thought of using class variables or the data function.

Comment: @Russel - You're welcome. :o) I wish I knew of a better solution.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping their was a jQuery hook to "withhold all other events until I say so, or until my current event has completed". Maybe I should ask Mr JR. :P

Comment: Pretty common to say: if(isRunning) return false; then after, set isRunning to true. Any additional events will be canceled. When done, set isRunning to false. Initialize isRunning in the global space and set it equal to false to begin with.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are various ways to prevent concurrent clicks from running the code.

One way is to `unbind('click')` on the element, then `.bind()` it again when you're ready.

I'd rather use some sort of flag. It could be a variable, but I'd rather assign a class to the element, like `.processing`, and remove it when done. So you would have the handler check for the existence of that class to determine of the code should run.

```
$('someElement').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    if($th.hasClass('processing'))
          return;
    $th.addClass('processing');
    // normal code to run
    // then when done remove the class
    $th.removeClass('processing');
});
```

Another option is to use the elements `.data()` to set a similar flag, like `$(this).data('processing', true);` Then set it to false when done.

Comment: @elo80ka - Thanks. I wish jQuery had something like `.disableHandler('click')` and `.enableHandler('click')` as an alternative to `.bind()/unbind()` and somewhat cluttered/hackish solutions like using classes or variables as flags. :o)

Comment: You should use the .data() function rather than adding a class that might accidentally impact the display of the element.

Comment: @bcherry - The nice thing about using a class is that it is (I'm pretty sure) a lighter weight operation than using `.data()`. If you're careful with naming your class, there shouldn't be any display ramifications.

Comment: Actually it might not be.  You'd be modifying the DOM, and then it would have to look through the CSS again to see if it needs to update styling, etc.  jQuery's `.data` method stores it in an in-memory hash that jQuery owns, and gets/sets to it will probably be faster.

Note that I have done no such benchmarking, this is all speculation.

Comment: @bcherry - Interesting thought. I'd be curious to know the performance difference. The browser looking for the class in CSS would be an in-memory lookup as well, and using native code, so it should be much faster than lookups in javascript, but touching the DOM is another issue. I've heard that calling `.data()` is very slow, such that it has been recommended to cache a reference to an element's data when recurring calls are required (as in this situation). Maybe I'll do some tests tomorrow.

Answer (score 27):

There is [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and return false as already stated.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: :-) for good measure... (though the question is different, I guess...)

Comment: yep, when I answered the question hadn't been clarified yet.

Comment: Yeah sorry @TehOne, I didn't express my question properly first time round.

Comment: @TechOne This not help to this question but it helpful for me. Thank you for shared.

Answer (score 12):

did you check out preventDefault?

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

you could also try `stopImmediatePropagation()` or `stopPropagation()`

---

You could also look into the [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event.

> Attach a handler to an event for the
>   elements. The handler is executed at
>   most once per element.

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` method really doesn't stop handlers. It prevents the default behavior of an element from activating (like an `<a>` taking you to its `href` location).

Comment: used e.stopImmediatePropagation(); worked. Thanks! Also, used unbind.

Comment: one() helped my case where the event was firing for every click. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Return `false` from your event handlers, or call `ev.stopPropagation()` in every handler.

Comment: @Mark - Re-read the question. *"my problem isn't preventing the bubbling of the event,"*

Comment: I clarified the question after he posted his answer.

Comment: @Russell - My comment was referring to @Mark's comment, not @Gintautas' answer. You're right, the answer was posted before your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple of options:

1. If your buttons/links will reload
   the page, you can simply unbind the
   click event handler:

   ```
   $('input:submit').click(fumction() {
       $(this).unbind('click');
       // Handle event here 
   })
   ```
2. You can disable the buttons, and re-enable them once you're done (I think
   this should also work with `<input
   type="image">`):

   ```
   $('input:submit').click(function() {
       $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       // It also helps to let the user know what's going on:
       $(this).val('Processing...');
       // Handle event here 
       $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
   })
   ```

   I don't think this works on links though.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to disable events (not unbind, just disable)?

Comment: @Russell: You can disable input elements. As far as I know, disabled elements don't raise events.

Comment: Yeah but an image link (anchor), for example, could raise a click event but is not an input field (as you said, disabling anchor elements doesn't work).

Comment: True...can't think of any way 'round that. Except, maybe, replacing your image links with `<input type="image">` elements. I'd probably go with Patrick's custom class solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and [event.isPropagationStopped()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/) for signalling:

Example:

```
$(button).click(function(e){
    if(e.isPropagationStopped())
        return; // propagation was stopped, so stop further execution

    // if you got this far - this event handler was called first
    // custom logic goes here

    // stop event propagation to signal other handlers
    e.stopPropagation();

    // if you need, call e.preventDefault() to prevent default behaviour
});
```

Repeat same logic for other event handlers.