# Allowing Only Single Touch jQuery Touchscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with an HP Touchscreen desktop computer, developing a simple website. I would like to prevent the user from "mashing" the screen clicking with eight fingers at one time. Is there a way in jQuery to allow only a single touch event to register at a time? So that when the first finger hits the screen, that is the one that is registered and all other touches are ignored until that finger reaches a `touchend`?

Comment: [Related:prevent other events after click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3473003)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Disable the input type (button, textbox, etc) after it is clicked, enable it after your logic has been completed.</strike>

**EDIT:** If you are trying to disable all touch events until touchend has been fired try something like this:

```
var isProcessing = false;

$(document).on("touchstart",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!isProcessing){
        isProcessing = true;
        //Do your stuff here
    }    
});

$(document).on("touchend",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    isProcessing = false; 
});
```

Comment: It's not necessarily a button though, it's the entire screen.

Comment: I can't quite think of a way where if the `body` receives a touch start event, to set a flag, and process the touch action. If the flag is set, ignore the touch. When `touchend` occurs reset the flag.

Comment: Updated my answer, I think we are thinking along the same lines.

Comment: Yes, this is closer. But I am thinking the `touchend` will need to be in a callback inside the `if`. I will also need to apply `.off()` to `touchstart` and rebind it after the flag is reset.

Comment: Well I don't the extent of your application, but this is the base logic you will need to prevent multiple touches.  Apply as you see fit.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the solution I used:

```
var isTouched = false;
var $document = $(document);

$document.on('touchstart', function () {
    if (!isTouched) {
        isTouched = true;
        $document.off('touchstart', function () {
            $document.on('touchend', function () {
                isTouched = false;
                $document.bind('touchstart');
            });
        });
     }
});
```