# Cannot stop JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the simplified scenario

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    alert('JQuery')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id='btn' value="Button" onclick="alert('onclick');return false;" />
```

two alerts are called even though I have returned false. How can I prevent script written inside ready event?

Comment: You should think about your profile pic and name, "Community" is a special user please don't use it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/5378743 "`return false` does not stop the event from bubbling up."

Comment: [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery prevent other events after a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472953/jquery-prevent-other-events-after-a-click)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) to prevents other listeners of the same event from being called.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    alert('JQuery')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id='btn' value="Button" onclick="alert('onclick');event.stopImmediatePropagation();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the alert('click') before you call the alert function.
Usually it can be done with `event.preventDefault()` used within a function

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    alert('JQuery')
  })
  function alert_first(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id='btn' value="Button" onclick="alert_first();alert('click);"/>
```