# How to prevent second click in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

It is not a duplicate of [jQuery prevent other events after a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472953/jquery-prevent-other-events-after-a-click)

In my case I use a Plugin to display a modal. Even if I use `unbind()` in the `deleteEntity` function, the modal is still displayed.

I have a list of buttons

```
<button name="deleteEntity">
```

I want these buttons to perform a delete action, so I attach the function like this :

```
$('button[name="deleteEntity"]').click(function () {return deleteEntity($(this)) })
```

In the `deleteEntity` function, here is what I want to perform

```
function deleteEntity(clickedEntity) {
    //Check if entity can be deleted 
    //If deletion is possible, display a modal form to confirm
    //Here return false for testing, modal is still displayed
    return false;
};
```

The modal form is a plugin. If answer of confirmation is yes, it calls the delete function.
This plugin is attached to the button like that :

```
$('button[name="deleteEntity"]').confirm({
    confirmed: function() {
        delete();
    },
});
```

The trouble is that I have 2 click events attached to the buttons. What I want to achieve is if the entity can be deleted (`deleteEntity` function) then display the modal, otherwise don't display it and that's all.

In other words is it possible to prevent the 2nd click event to trigger (attached in the Plugin)?

Thanks.

***Here is the plugin***

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.confirm = function (options) {
    this.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.confirm.defaults, {
            confirmed: function () { },
            cancelled: function () { }
        }, options);

        var modalHeader = '';
        if (settings.title !== '') {
            modalHeader =
                '<div class="modal-header">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                    '<h4 class="modal-title">' + settings.title + '</h4>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        var modalHTML =
            '<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">' +
                '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                    '<div class="modal-content">' +
                        modalHeader +
                        '<div class="modal-body">'
                            + settings.text +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                            '<button class="confirm btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Oui</button>' +
                            '<button class="cancel btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Non</button>';
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';

        var modal = $(modalHTML);

        modal.find(".confirm").click(function () {
            settings.confirmed();
        });

        $("body").append(modal);
        modal.modal('show');
        return this;
    });
};

$.fn.confirm.defaults = {
    text: "Are you sure?",
    title: "",
}
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: What do you mean there is a 2nd click? where is it? where is it registered? what is the plugin?

Comment: I have edited the question with the plugin code

Comment: refer this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473021/4425004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery prevent other events after a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472953/jquery-prevent-other-events-after-a-click)

Comment: Maybe the trouble is that when the delete function is executed, the click event to display the modal is already binded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is what I did :

Dynamically adding a data attribute on the button, depending on whether or not I want to display the modal :

```
function deleteEntity(clickedEntity) {
    //Logic here (controller)

    if (isReadyToDelete)
    {
        clickedEntity.data("tobeconfirmed", "true");
    }
    else
    {
        clickedEntity.data("tobeconfirmed", "false");
    }
};
```

And then modify the plugin as follow :

```
var isModalToDisplay = ($(this).data("tobeconfirmed"));
if (isModalToDisplay=="true") {
    modal.modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click eventhandler should return false, if you want to prevent other eventhandlers to run:

First, change this:

```
$('button[name="deleteEntity"]').click(function () { return deleteEntity($(this)) })
```

Now your eventhandler returns `true` (contimue other handlers) or `false` (stop other eventhandlers).

Second, change this:

```
function deleteEntity(clickedEntity) {
    return entityCanBeDeleted; //return either true or false
};
```

That should prevent other eventhandlers if you return false;

Comment: I'm returning false in `deleteEntity` to test but modal still displayed...

Comment: Edit your question then, show the code instead of the 2 comments.